young animal vs. baby animal
The word 'kid' to me means a goat that has not yet attained adulthood, and is not fully mature.
But does 'young goat' mean the same or could it mean a young fully mature goat?
And would 'baby goat' mean exactly the same as 'kid'?
I am asking this question about 'goats' but I could have gone for 'dogs' or 'cats' or...
In most cases there is a specific name for the animal that has not reached maturity (puppy, kitten, etc.). I am not sure that is always the case. Take 'pigeon' for instance. I guess the expression would be 'chick pigeon', but would 'young pigeon' and 'baby pigeon' work and mean the same?
Many thanks

When a word for a young animal is used for more than one species we usually place the term for the young animal after the animal type word thus pigeon chick, wolf cub, seal pup, zebra foal, etc.

The proper or formal word for a young pigeon is a squab.

I might note that in Britain (I don't know about elsewhere) talking about a 'baby animal', e.g. baby cow, baby dog, baby sheep, etc, may be considered childish (i.e. more suitable for very small children as, also, is saying 'lady dog', or 'daddy chicken'). The prudish Victorians tried to make people call a bull a 'gentleman cow'.

The distinction between the terms "baby [animal]," "young [animal]," and the specific term used for that animal's young (like "puppy" or "kitten") revolves around the stage of development and specificity in language.
1. Specific Term for Young Animal:

Definition: This is the particular, often species-specific term used to describe a young animal. Examples include "puppy" for dogs, "kitten" for cats, "calf" for cows, "foal" for horses, and "kid" for goats, or "squab for pigeon.
Stage of Development: These terms typically refer to a very specific early stage in the animal's life, usually right after birth until they reach a certain level of independence or maturity (but still juvenile).
Precision: Using the specific term provides precise information about the animal's species and developmental stage. For example, "kitten" immediately tells you the young animal is a cat and at a specific early stage of life. However, many of these terms are only really used in very specific contexts. For example, "squab" is almost exclusively used in a culinary context.

2. Baby [Animal]:

Definition: "Baby [animal]" is a general term used to describe a very young animal, typically shortly after birth or hatching. It's often synonymous with the specific term for young animals, like "puppy" or "kitten."
Stage of Development: The term usually refers to an animal in the earliest stage of life, often when it is still dependent on its parents for food and care.
Usage: This term is commonly used in more informal or casual contexts and is easily understood, even if someone doesn't know the specific term for that animal's young. For example, in my own experience, a native speaker is far more likely to say "baby platypus" than "puggle" but you may encounter such words in more formal contexts.

3. Young [Animal]:

Definition: "Young [animal]" is a broader, more general term that can refer to an animal that is past the "baby" stage but is not yet fully mature. This term is more flexible and can cover a wider range of ages.
Stage of Development: A "young [animal]" could be anywhere from just past infancy to nearing adulthood, depending on the context. For instance, a "young dog" could be a puppy or a juvenile dog that is not fully grown.
Usage: This term is useful when you want to emphasize that the animal is not fully mature but do not need to specify exactly how young it is. It may also be seen as a formal way of referring to a juvenile animal (compared to 'baby') when the specific term is not known or is only used in a specific context.

Summary of Differences:

Specific Term (e.g., "puppy"): Refers to a specific and defined stage in the animal's early life.
Baby [Animal]: Refers to the very young stage of an animal, often synonymous with the specific term but more general and less precise.
Young [Animal]: A broader term that covers any stage from infancy to near physical maturity. Often used synonymously with "adolescent".

As a final answer, I would say:
Young animal usually refers to an animal not at physical maturity but it may occasionally refer to an animal that has recently attained maturity.

+1 The terms are explained well.

Did you get AI to write that?
